# How to upgrade 2008 report definition to 2010

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2012, ssrs-2008

I have two reports in a report project that have somehow been updated to use the 2010 report defintion;

```
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition" ...>
```

However, all other reports in the project, including new reports added to the project use the 2008 definition;

```
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" ...>
```

How can i force this update across the other reports in the project?

***=EDIT=***

The Visual Studio 2012 [compatibility chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh266747.aspx) specific to SQL Server Report Project says;

> If you add a feature that’s specific to Visual Studio 2012, the report
>   schema is upgraded automatically and you can no longer open the
>   project in Visual Studio 2010 SP1.

Now i just need to figure out what a 2012 feature is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to add a *Map* (2012 feature) to the report, save it, then delete the Map, and save again.  Note that adding the Map and deleting before saving will not enforce the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

In the report properties find InitialPageName an give it a value. InitialPageName is a 2010 feature, as well as the PageName property that can be set on various report elements, such as Tablix and Graph.